# My PC doesn't recognize my GameCube controller

Tags: controllers, nintendo-gamecube

I'm using a third party adapter from MIMD and also third party GameCube controllers.
The issue here is that the PC does recognize the adapter but not the controllers themselves.
Im using CSL gamepad controllers and my PC is a HP Pavilion 15 Notebook.

Comment: Can you provide us with the exact model number or a link to the adapter you are using? Sounds like drivers or other utility software is missing

Comment: Hey @bugle - an edit was suggested by an anonymous user with a product link. If this was you, and you want to add to your post, please sign in to edit it -- that way it won't require any extra approval, and we can be sure it was you.